# td { position:relative; } overflows into the table border

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/L83y3/

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td class="right">more stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table
{
    border:10px solid green;
}
td
{
    padding:20px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.right
{
    position:relative;
}
```

has a solid uninterrupted green border for Chrome 13, Safari 5, IE7
but results in this for IE9, IE8, FF5, FF4, FF3.6

[image: bug]

How can I get a solid border all the way around, but still have `position:relative` in the right cell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apply z-index:-1;

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/L83y3/1/

```
.right
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1
}
```

Comment: well, looks like that worked for my simplified example, but made the entire `td` disappear in my actual project.

Comment: Give [position:relative] and [z-index:2;] for the table and give a [z-index:1] for the [.right] class

Comment: A problem with this solution is that you cant place a ribbon or such over the cell border since the border will be above the ribbon.
However, Yash solution hasn't got this problem.

Comment: With this solution, you cannot have a background-color on a parent element, or the content will disappear.

Answer (score 55):

Background clipping just did the trick.
Just apply `"background-clip: padding-box;"` on the `th` and it works.

according to the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip.

"No background is drawn below the border (background extends to the outside edge of the padding)."

Comment: [Only IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip), but otherwise the simplest by far

Comment: IE 11 and still needs this!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer instead since Mr TK solution has flaws.

Comment: Yash, You are brilliant :)

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to trigger a bug in Chrome now where it only draws part of the background even though the padding on the cell is zero.

Comment: After eight years this is still life saver :)

Answer (score 12):

You can't reliably change the `position` of a table cell, some browsers (older Safari versions at least, the latest one seems to have fixed this problem) will force table cells (and rows) to `position: static` no matter what you say.

If you need to absolutely position something inside a table cell, you'll need to put a relatively positioned `<div>` (or other block element) inside the cell and then put everything else inside that:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td><div class="right">more stuff</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then tweak the CSS:

```
.right {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And the obligatory live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KUshG/

I suspect that takes care of the problem you're seeing and does away with some problems that you haven't seen yet.

Comment: that works, but i was hoping to avoid the extra `div` inside the `td`, which has worked ok for me to this point. can you think of any of those haven't seen yet scenarios?

Comment: @qntmfred: Safari version "current - 1" would be one, the last version made all table cells `position: static`. I'm not sure about other browsers. The `<div>` is certainly an ugly hack of last resort.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use position on table-cells.

Just wrap the cells content into a relative div:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td class="right">
            <div style="position:relative;">more stuff</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```