# nth-child:odd/even removes td border on IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-selectors

I'm having this issue where i use `nth-child(odd)` to color a table.

In IE9 it paints the TDs the right color but then their border is not visible. Any idea on how to fix this?

Example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/tYSZW/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `position:relative` in this declaration and it will work.

```
tbody td{
    font-size:12px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That was it !, I spent a long hour trying to figure out why it had suddenly stopped working. I moved and replaced everything on my CSS but never touched that declaration. Thanks !

Any technical idea why this happens ?

Comment: It seems that TD elements were not intended to have positions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021085/td-positionrelative-overflows-into-the-table-border

Answer (score 3):

Amazing. I added the position:relative to my .CSS and now the borders appear within the nth-child! Before the background color was present but not the borders.

```
 .variations tr:nth-child(5n) td {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #bbb195;
   filter: none;
   position: relative;
```