# position:relative hides border in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a table where the top row is position:relative.  In IE 9 adding the position attribute hides the border between the cells.  (This doesn't happen in Chrome).

My question is similar to [this one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021085/td-positionrelative-overflows-into-the-table-border) but I can't set the z-index of the top row lower than the other rows because it is going to be a fixed header that needs to have a higher z-index.

HTML

```
<table border="1">
            <tr >
                <td class="locked">header 1</td>
                <td class="locked">header 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td>data 1a</td>
                <td>data 1b</td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td>data 2a</td>
                <td>data 2b</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

CSS

```
.locked {
            position: relative;
            background-color: Yellow;
        }
```

[image]

How do I get the border to show up, but keep z-index greater than other cells?

Edit:
Here is jquery code that explains why the header position is relative.
1. It allows the header to scroll horizontally and vertically.
2. The header stays on the top of screen when you scroll down the page more then 153 pixels.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        var off = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (off < 153) {
            $(".frozenTop").css("top", 0);
        } else {
            $(".frozenTop").css("top", off - 153);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to position those cells at all?

Comment: the top row will be a fixed header using jquery.  i left out the code to keep it simple.

Comment: What is the `position: relative` accomplishing for you?

Comment: @AndrewThomas - that's an important aspect of this question, it may be other styles are being applied by the JS when its executed.  Try going into a DOM inspector and looking for *all* of the transformed CSS.

Comment: also, you should include the script - that may be the problem... It's always a fine line between providing too much info and not enough on this site.  But in this case, i'd say at least mentioning hey, this is the *end goal* i'm trying to achieve... that way people can actually see where you're trying to go with it and stop you if you're doing something dumb.

Comment: @KevinBoucher I have added an edit to the bottom of the question to explain the purpose of the relative positioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Maybe Helpful

```
<td class="locked"><div>header 1</div></td>
<td class="locked"><div>header 2</div></td>

table {
border-spacing: 0px;
}
.locked {
  position: relative;
  border:none;
}
.locked div{
  border:2px black solid;
  background-color: Yellow;
  margin:-2px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zL3NA/3/)

Comment: This is close. IE9 now has white spacing between the cells. (curiously they don't show up in the jsfiddle pane).

Comment: @AndrewThomas,I changed my answer take a look.

Comment: Reproducing the border in the div is one way, but you can use the actual table cell border if you make the table cells "own" their border.  Add table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0 } and the cells should then each have separate borders that move with the cell, and zero space in between.  See http://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/a9awheqd/

Answer (score 25):

If only for CSS3 supported browsers, CSS3 property *background-clip* can help:

```
.locked {
    position: relative;
    background-color: Yellow;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Details about this property:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-clip