# TD an TH with relative position, breaking out of overflow: scroll parent in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bootstrap-4

This started recently I think, and only seems to be an issue in chrome. The table-responsive class is supposed to contain the table, for scrolling when there's overflow, but in chrome the td/th elements are flowing out of the container.

[image]

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div class="compact card-columns">
    <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Header</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Light card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Header</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Light card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Header</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And the CSS:**

```
td, th {
  position: relative;
}
```

I've also reproduced it here in a pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xopXxm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [td { position:relative; } overflows into the table border](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7021249/2410655)

Comment: @DavidLiang That's not it, the cells already have position relative. I've also tried adding a wrapper div position relative, but, the elements deeper in the chain will then once again, break out of the scroll. But, not only that, they are visible if you have an A tag, for example, you will see you will get a hover cursor even though the element is supposed to be hidden.

Comment: No, I was saying if you put relative position on the cells, in Chrome only, they will overflow the table! And yes I can reproduce your overflow issue with anchor links, which is weird. I don't know what caused that one. My guess is this is another bug from Chrome?  Fix to the overflows caused by relative cells: don't set relative position on them. Fix to the overflows caused by anchor tags: explicitly set them to either `inline-block` or `block`. Apparently the default `inline` will make them overflow the table in Chrome!

Comment: @DavidLiang The reason I have to have a relative item in the cell, a div or directly on the anchor, is that I need to add absolute positioned elements inside the cells. So, I don't really have another option. It's definitely something new in Chrome since 73, because the code worked fine before.

Comment: Yea it looks like Google Chrome has bugs on any element with relative positioning inside a table cell. The element is not getting any height even you set it to 100%!

Answer (score 0):

[image]i guess because of your font-size its getting overflow. i don't know it will satisfy you or not. try by giving a font size to TH,TD

```
td, th {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 6.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove class `card-columns` from your top most div
because it has property style

`widows: 1;`

your `tr` inherited this property which cause issue.
So just remove `card-columns` css class.
Find more in widow [w3s](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_orphans.asp)